# yet another confusing generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I've got a static method inside Utility class :

```
public static final <T extends Foo & IBar>  Foo1<T> getBaz(Class<T> fooAndIBarClazz)
```

I have another class:

```
public class FooBar<T extends Foo> {
     private Class<T> fooClazz;
//...
}
```

From inside the instance of `FooBar` I want to call `Utility.getBaz()`

```
public void aMethod() {
   Utility.getBaz(fooClazz); // fails with not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter
   //Utility.<IBar>getBaz(fooClazz); // fails as well
}
```

Is it possible to call the utility method in this generic way without additional casting?

Comment: Why doesn't `T` in `FooBar` extend from `IBar` AND `Foo` like needed in `getBaz`?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Is the actual value of `fooClazz` implementing `IBar` though? Because in that case you shouldn't even attempt any casting.

Comment: cant do :) some Foo do not implement IBar

Comment: Well, then you can't use `getBaz()`, cast or no cast.

Comment: if some Foo don't implement IBar, you should'nt use Foo & IBar ...  why would you even want to?

Comment: No, not the way its defined.  You've defined a Utility class that takes an object as a parameter that is both a Foo and an IBar.  However, in your FooBar class, fooClazz is typed as a Foo.  There is no guarantee that your fooClazz member is of type IBar, and hence the error.

Comment: @StevenMastandrea yes, this looks like multiple inheritance to me. But compiler "knows" that it must be a Foo instance, why not allow it to cast to IBar?

Comment: @Funtik Are all Foos IBars? If not, you can't cast it to be one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics in Java add compile-time type checking, and basically help you to avoid casting.  If there's something you cannot do with casting, you also won't be able to do it with generics.

If you cannot confirm that the class you're calling the method with implements IBar, what do you expect the called method to do with it?  Clearly, it requires the methods that IBar defines (otherwise it wouldn't have that signature).  So it cannot perform its job.

Comment: Yeah, the first 2 lines really explain it all.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code seemed incomplete. This all works for me.

Foobar

```
public class FooBar<T extends Foo> {

    public void aMethod() { 
        Utility.getBaz( Foo.class ) ;
    }

}
```

Foo

```
public class Foo<T> implements IBar {

}
```

Utility

```
public class Utility {
    public static final <T extends Foo & IBar>  Foo<T> getBaz(Class<T> fooAndIBarClazz){

        try {
            return fooAndIBarClazz.newInstance() ;
        } catch( InstantiationException e ) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null ;  

    }
}
```

Ibar

```
public interface IBar {

}
```

Comment: there is an error in your listing. My Foo does not implement IBar. Otherwise I would not need to specify both <T extends Foo & IBar>